# Hatcher 4.1.6 typo?

Tags: homotopy-theory, covering-spaces

Problem 4.1.6 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book says:

Suppose that $p : (\tilde{X}, \tilde{A}, \tilde{x_0}) \to (X,A,x_0)$ is a covering space with $\tilde{A} = p^{-1}(A)$. Show that the induced map $p_* : \pi_n((\tilde{X}, \tilde{A}, \tilde{x_0}) \to \pi_n(X,A,x_0)$ is an isomorphism for $n > 1$.

Using the long exact sequence of the pair, this is clear for $n > 2$. For $n = 2$, it is easy by doing some diagram chasing to show that $p_*$ is injective. However, it is not clear to me that it is surjective.

I believe I have a counter example:

Edit: This example doesn't work, as is pointed out in comments. I'm still not sure why this is true though.

Let $X = \bar{\mathbb{D}}^2 = \tilde{X}$, the closed unit disc, and $A = S^1 = \partial X$. Let $p : \tilde{X} \to X$ be the squaring map. Then using the naturality of the long exact sequence of the pair, the map $\pi_2(\tilde{X}, \tilde{A})$ agrees with $\pi_1(\tilde{A}) \to \pi_1(A)$, which is multiplication by $2$ from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. This map is not surjective.

Maybe I'm missing something -- or perhaps this is a typo in the text? I don't see it in the errata list, and the statement of the problem is from most recent version.

Comment: I don't see how $p$ is a covering map there. It's a branched two-fold covering map, branching at the origin.

Comment: @BalarkaSen That's an important point! And of course the example collapses if you remove it. Thanks Balarka. :)

Comment: @user60589 There was actually a problem with it.

Comment: @AreaMan No problem. I guess the distinction between algebraic geometer's covering map (which *are* branched covers) and topologist's covering map  was the point of confusion :)

Comment: @BalarkaSen You could give me credit and say that, but I really did mean covering map. I was being careless. Admittedly, the language ambiguities didn't help me think clearly - I'll have to be more careful about this. Still puzzled about proving surjectivity though...

Comment: @BalarkaSen At least, one would need the induced map $\pi_1(\tilde{A}) \to \pi_1(A)$ to be surjective in order to apply the five lemma. So that is how I came to my failed counter example

Comment: @AreaMan Oh you are right!

Comment: @AreaMan By choosing $A=X$ one can see that the induced map on $\pi_1$ does not have to be surjective.

Comment: @user60589 Sorry, got a little confused there. I did mean to say $p_*$; basically looking at $\pi_2(X, A)$ is more useful than $\pi_1(A)$ here (like you did) because you want to lift the map. Covering maps are of course not surjective on $\pi_1$, precisely because the circle is not simply connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For surjectivity at $p_*\colon \pi_2(\tilde{X},\tilde{A},\tilde{x_0}) \to \pi_2(X,A,x_0)$ note that an element of $\pi_2(X,A,x_0)$ can be represented by a map
$$ x\colon (\Bbb D^2, \Bbb S^{1},s_0)\to (X,A,x_0) $$
since $\Bbb D^2$ is simply connected this map can be lifted to $\tilde{X}$,
so we have a unique map
$$\tilde{x} \colon (\Bbb D^2,s_0) \to (\tilde{X}, \tilde{x_0}) $$
with $p \circ \tilde{x} = x$. We have $\tilde{x} (\Bbb S^1) \subset \tilde A $ and thus $\tilde{x}$ represents a presage of $x$. Hence the maps is surjective.

Comment: Thanks! Of course it has to be topological, not pure algebra...